# How to keep shareReplay alive when there are no subscribers?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to share a hot `Observable` between multiple subscribers and emit the latest value to new subscribers. I am trying to achieve this with `shareReplay(1)`, however, the first subscriber fails to retrieve the latest value because the `shareReplay` operator doesn't do anything when there is no subscription, so it doesn't store anything for the first subscriber.

How do I fix this without having a permanent subscription just to keep `shareReplay` alive?

Comment: `shareReplay()` accepts an optional config object where you can set [`resetOnRefCountZero`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.1.0/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L37-L47) so maybe that's what you're looking for. Or maybe you want to turn the source Observable into a "hot" Observable using [`connectable`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/connectable)

Comment: @martin I am using RxJS 6 and I only see a `refCount` option is that what you're talking about? I tried to set it at `false` but it didn't change the behavior in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem using `publishReplay(1)` instead of `shareReplay(1)`:

```
const subject = new Subject()

const source$ = subject.pipe(publishReplay(1))
source$.connect();

subject.next(1)
subject.next(2)
subject.next(3)
source$.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
subject.next(4)
subject.next(5)
subject.next(6)
```

Output:

```
3
4
5
6
```

The important part is that with `publishReplay`, you can control when the subscription starts (`source$.connect()`). `shareReplay` will start only with the first subscription.

Comment: As it's by the question intended but never forget that if you don't unintentionally handle subscriptions (like .connect is aswell) you have a memory leak in your application.